# What is the Cylon Recon Drone?

Tags: spaceship, battlestar-galactica, cylon

Battlestar Wiki has an article: http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Cylon_reconnaissance_drone

I don't recall this craft at all, and the aforementioned site doesn't have a picture. Is it ever shown on-screen? The wiki references the miniseries and the season 1 finale, but I'm not sure if these were on-screen appearances of the vessel or merely mentions in dialog.

Comment: there are some odd looking ships flying around the basestar in "Kobol's Last Gleaming" but neither Boomer nor Racetrack identifies them as recon drones. I'd have to watch the miniseries again to see if they're the same as what Starbuck identified.

Comment: I just had a look - I can see some Cylon Freighters, raiders and heavy raiders, but nothing else...have you spotted anything else and could comment on exactly where it appeared? (The Cylon Freighter is itself a rarely seen ship so maybe you meant that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that we really don't know. The recon drones are only mentioned once by Starbuck in part 2 of the miniseries, around the 57:36 mark.

Unfortunately, this is what's on screen at that time:

[image]

That's a loud speaker. Starbuck's dialogue,

> Starbuck: I didn't get an accurate account, but it looks like two base stars with ten fighter squadrons and two recon drone attachments patrolling the area.

is heard only over the radio. We never actually get to see what she saw at that time.

The early miniseries featured elements that weren't found in the rest of the series, such as Boxey, a character famous in the original series. It's safe to presume that the recon drones were never developed as a separate unit, possibly due to the added SFX costs. We see Raiders and Heavy Raiders, but not Recon drones.

In Season 1 Episode 9, *Tigh Me Up, Tigh Me Down*, we see a single Raider performing recon around the 12:57 mark:

> DUALLA: Cylon Raider bearing 738 carom 005. Relative zero. Close with enemy, destroy. Acknowledge.
>   APOLLO: We're on it, Galactica. He jumped right in front of us. His mistake.
>   TIGH: How many?
>   GAETA: Single Raider. Looks like a recon patrol.

This reinforces the idea that it's just Raiders that do recon, and a separate type of (visibly different) Raider doesn't perform that task.

These are the screen grabs of that particular Cylon:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I knew I remember that last scene, but I ended up having to search scripts manually for each mention of "Raider". Thankfully it was in season one! I'm sure there were other similar cases.